# Did Hitler and Nazi officials give interviews and cooperate with the Weimar republic general press?

Tags: hitler, nazism, revolution, weimar-republic, journalism

Politicians often purposely avoid being interviewed by journalists based on numerous arguments and if they do get interviewed they might ensure to film the interview with their own crew to expose possible "edit fallacies".

When I have learned on how the Nazis gained popularity before 1933 (before Hitler became a chancellor); first in Munich, then more broadly in Bavaria, then in all of Germany I have learned of the following methods:

- Public speaking in events
- Provoking audience to start brawls in events that were later be press-reviewed (thus exposing more to the party)
- Using sticker-signs and suggesting pamphlets
- Using propaganda megaphone-equipped cars
- Using symbols that were grasped "mysterious" and "charismatic"
- Using hierarchical system of commanders and commandeered that were grasped "charismatic"
- Publishing their own printed material with tremendous amount of antisemitism and racism

### My problem

I have never come across data about them being interviewed or somehow cooperating with the general German press of the time.

### My question

Did Hitler and Nazi officials give interviews and cooperate with the Weimar republic general press (or did they vehemently refuse to do so in comparison to other political leaders in the Weimar republic)?

Comment: If you can get your hands on a copy, you might find [Press and Politics in the Weimar Republic](https://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199547784.001.0001/acprof-9780199547784) of interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that with "Weimar" the question asked exclusively about pre-dictatorship Germany then for the timespan from 1919–1934 we have to observe:

> (October 1930)
>   It's gonna be a clean winter. Nominations just against us. But the scoundrels will be wrong if they think they'll break us by terror and persecution. **Interview with a radio man. I gave him a piece of my mind.** About the "neutrality" of radio [!] and the cowardice of the government to openly admit its party politics. At home reading and music.
>
> (27 March 1933 (*[Hotel] Kaiserhof* [(Imperial Court)])
>   I dictate a sharp essay against the atrocity of the Jews. His announcement alone makes the whole bunch of people crumble. One must use such methods. Generosity does not impress the Jew. One must show them that one is determined to do everything. I will immediately pass on my appeal to Munich by telex so that it can be transmitted to the Führer. He will decide when the action should be set in motion. The Jewish press is whimpering with horror and fear. All the Jewish associations in Germany declare their loyalty to the government. **We work with interviews as much as we can;** but only a very big action can help us out of this calamity now. A glorious spring lies over Germany.
>
> (June 20th, 1933)
>   Amt Göring/Körner in matters of broadcasting – an impertinence. I'm furious and want to fly to Hitler. But I'm letting the matter mature. Met Arabs. Constant interviews. This makes me want to puke.
>
> <sub>From Joseph Goebbels' diaries. (— Ralf Georg Reuth (Ed). "Jospeh Goebbels Tagebücher 1924–1945", Piper: München, Zürich, <sup>3</sup>2003. (My translation))</sub>

There are numerous interviews still available, on the net if you use a decent search engine. Or just press archives.

The general development was that at first no one (from the non-local Germannewspapers) was that much interested in talking with them, after the Hitler-Ludendorff-Putsch they were not a real player anymore. But after 1928 they tried to use the press as much as possible.
While [Hitler himself was somewhat less keen](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4634275) on giving back-and-forth interviews to be published, others enjoyed the limelight and attention much more. From 1929–1934 these cooperations were 'naturally' used to advertise the partyline wherever and whenever they could.

The highly partisan press landscape of Germany at the time meant that this type of cooperation was quite difficult with all left leaning papers, but then there were much more liberal and conservative right-leaning papers anyway. Thus, "cooperating" seems a bit of a strange word if applied to "the press".
Curiously, giving interviews to international newspapers, Italian, French, Spanish and especially American, seems to be the highlight of any nazi's day.

<sub>— Bernhard Fulda: "Press and Politics in the Weimar Republic", Oxford University Press: Oxford, New York, 2009.</sub>

Another highly relevant example is found in 1923 when Hitler did give an interview in which he pondered the idea that 'ideally all Jews needed to be  killed'…
<sub>( Quoted in: — Christian Hartmann, Thomas Vordermayer, Othmar Plöckinger & Roman Töppel (Eds.): Hitler, Mein Kampf. Eine kritische Edition. Institut für Zeitgeschichte München: Berlin, München, 2016, Vol1, p208.)</sub>

Or

> In an interview with a National Socialist journalist in June 1924, while he was actually in Landsberg prison (where he wrote Mein Kampf), Hitler explained how in the past he had been too lenient in his racism. Now he had to apply the harshest methods against ‘the plague of the world’ (i.e. the Jews).
>   <sub>— Martyn Housden: "Hitler Study of a Revolutionary?", Routledge: London, New York, 2000.</sub>

Of course, they had also quite a troubled and abusive relationship with the truth, a difficult situation for any marriage councillor. A real classic is of course this interview just on the eve of when authoritarian rule exploded into full scale dictatorship. It almost looks as if critical stance was still tolerated:

> "What do you say, Minister, to the talk that the Nazis themselves have set fire the Reichstag?"

To this answered Hans Frank, SA member and Nazi party member since 1923, Nazi Minister of Justice in Bavaria and - so the official title - 'Reich Commissioner for the Equalization of Justice and for the Renewal of the Legal Order'. This interview was published in [*Kölnische Zeitung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6lnische_Zeitung) on 21 September 1933. He said:

> "It is the cries of the caught thief who roars: 'Stop the thief', and further: 'Fires and destruction are the weapons of the communist world revolution.'

Comment: +1, Based on the closing citation it appears that part of the preceding text is meant to be formatted as a quote but the format is not displaying in your answer and it's not clear as written where the quote begins/ends.

Comment: I give this bounty to LangLangC in a suggestion to him to make the answer a bit shorter if this is possible (perhaps splitting and shortening some passages a bit) but of course I will gladly, and humbly, give this bounty anyway.